# For non-special-character textbox, should I use inline validating message or block users from inputing invalid characters?

Tags: input, validation

I have one textbox that means to allow no special characters. Now, I have to choose below approaches:

1. Display inline validating message say something like "char * is not allowed" (A) or "Your input cannot contain %$*&" (B) when user input chars in black-list.
2. Block user from enter invalid chars. Meaning that if user hit chars that are in black-list, nothing would happend.

Which of the approaches should I take?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With approach 2 (block invalid characters), the user might type something quickly and end up with a result which looks nothing like what they wanted.

Let's say a user-name field should only contain standard unaccented characters. A user could enter `Juergen` without a problem; but attempting to use <kbd>ü</kbd> instead of `ue` would be ignored and the user would end up with `Jrgen`.

Attempting to create a username like `$4nta Cl4u$` would be similarly stymied: `ntaClu`.

This is bad: the user would have to work out what had been omitted and why and then correct it. Approach 2 should be avoided.

Method 1 (validation message) is therefore to be preferred — and this should be inline during entry rather than returned after the form is submitted.

I would prefer adding the user's invalid characters to the message as they are entered. Thus the message `You cannot use ü` would appear as soon as that character was typed; and in the second example it would end up as `You cannot use $4[space]`. (Actually using `[space]`, not a blank character.)

In Method 1, it would be useful to make some help available as well in order that the user can find out exactly what *is* valid. That could appear as a tooltip, or open a separate page.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1oAZT.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: You need to be careful when you say which characters are allowed.  "Special chars", "Invalid chars" and "Upper- and Lower-case letters without accents" are all very culture / system specific terms.  


If you are storing as US-ASCII then you cannot accept "ß" or "ı" which are lower case letters without diacritics (and not *special* or *invalid* to anyone who uses them regularly).  

Better still would be to change your backend to UTF-8 :)