# How to clearly state to the User what characters are valid

Tags: labels, validation

I'm trying to determine the best way to inform the User that an input accepts certain special characters. Alphanumerics are simple enough, but I feel like I'm losing clarity when I get to characters such as . and -.
One style I've tried is this:

```
Valid characters include A-z, 0-9, and (._-).
```

Where the parenthesis wrap the valid characters, but when the parenthesis are not valid, it seems too easy for them to be mistaken as part of the list.

The style I'm leaning towards is the following:

```
Valid Characters include A-z, 0-9, '.', '_', and '-'.
```

But I feel as though the single quotes clutter things up, and makes it easy to lose yourself in the list, especially as it grows. Is there any way to convey this information that's accepted as 'better', or are there in fact better ways to go about this entirely?

Comment: This is very closely related to [another question about validation](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/46052/for-non-special-character-textbox-should-i-use-inline-validating-message-or-blo) but I'm not sure if it's a duplicate. It might be.

Comment: @AndrewLeach It's definitely similar, but that question seems more related to When validation information should be displayed. I was concerned with verbiage. Unfortunately in my case, I have no choice as to the when.

Comment: For better user experience, a good rule of thumb for presenting such complex requirements is to question the actual requirements. Is it so absolutely neccessary to have this exact limitation? Could you go out of your way and change your systems (perhaps re-encoding or 'escaping' their original input) so that there aren't arbitrary sets of 'valid characters' anymore?  The best UX for this message would be no message at all, except when completely abnormal edge cases are encountered ("Please don't input 2 gigabytes of text here").

Comment: Potential shorter version for the letters: `A-z`

Comment: Personally, I would really like it it if it just said "Your username must match the pattern _`insert-relevant-regex-here`_," because then there is no ambiguity about allowed characters, Unicode, allowed lengths, or any weird restrictions that some sites seem to like. Unfortunately, most users do not know regular expressions, so this is unlikely to ever happen.

Comment: Although the best solution is actually "don't impose these restrictions on your users".

Comment: Perhaps this is the opposite, but if you have a minimum requirement (common for password fields), then repeat the rules when someone gets their password wrong, not just when they create it. I get so frustrated with sites that require some arbitrary length or character pattern so I cannot use the password I want and can remember, so I have to modify. When I return and fail to log on with my preferred choice, a reminder of the rules will usually remind me how I modified it to fit.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Clutter is problematic. Emphasizing the valid characters might be enough. E.g.:

> Valid characters are **A**-**Z** **a**-**z** **0**-**9** **.** **_** **-**.

Displaying them with different color might also help.

Answer (score 34):

Here is some advice :

- forbid characters only if it is absolutely necessary (I hate when I
  cannot use _ in my nickname)
- display a message only to the user who tries to use one of these. Other users won't be bothered
- if the user enter a forbidden caracter, just don't consider it and explain him why.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqG5bt.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: I do like this answer, but there are restrictions in my environment that would break flow if I informed on each invalid keystroke. It's a problem, I know.

Comment: This is good feedback, but trial-and-error can get pretty annoying. I'd say give the list *and* do this.

Comment: I disagree. I hate it when I spend five minutes thinking of a new password for a site, only to be told that it’s unacceptable _after_ I’ve typed it.

Comment: @Scott: I think that is where his first point comes in. There just shouldn't be a limitation on characters for passwords in the first place.

Comment: If I read the question correctly the problem was how to inform the user that *additional* characters are allowed, not that certain characters are *not* allowed. That wouldn't work with this approach.

Comment: But then, blacklisting (instead of the usual whitelisting) has a higher risk of security and encoding issues issues if not exercised well (and if escaping and/or validation is not implemented properly). Strange characters may be passed down to the plumbing where some library might use just that strange character to do evil; this is easier handled with whitelisting, but then my I18N framework-knowledge could need an update.

Comment: Showing all characters you don't allow in the first attempt would work better. http://imgur.com/AEoYUTJ

Comment: I **really** get angry when I’m not being told upfront which characters are (generally; eMail address validation is probably not a good example for this) valid. I consider this bad advice for the general case. Do show all valid characters first.

Comment: @AyeshK That works if there are only a few disallowed characters like in filenames. In the OP's case there are about a hundred thousand disallowed characters, so the list would be pretty long. So they they need to display a whitelist, not a blacklist.

Comment: This is very dangerous if the text field is a password. It's far too easy to type the password in quickly and miss the warning text. (It also reveals part of the user's password to anyone looking over their shoulder.) You could easily imagine a user quickly entering their favorite password into the field missing the warning, tabbing to the next one, entering it again to confirm, and clicking the "Done" button. Now their password is something other than what they think they typed because the one invalid character was ignored.

Comment: @user1118321  As x3ro said, none character should be forbidden for a password. This system will not be efficient if you are too much restrictive

Answer (score 14):

You could display blocks of each character type, like this:

**Allowed characters:** `A-Z` `a-z` `0-9` `-` `_` `.`

Answer (score 13):

I would suggest to mention about the characters that are not allowed, because number of invalid characters is always lesser for any required input. This will help to reduce clutter. See the given example from windows explorer.

[image]

Comment: In my case the number of valid special characters is actually the smaller set. I know that's not the norm, though, so it's a good answer for most cases.

Answer (score 10):

I'd leave out A-z and possibly even 0-9 as these should be obviously allowed. For the *additional* characters I'd go with their names rather than the symbols

> You may also use underscore, dash and period.

Comment: It's worth giving the symbols as well if US English isn't guaranteed to be your users' instinctive language (in UK English these would be underline/underscore, hyphen and full stop, goodness knows about some of the rest of the commonwealth). It's technically not a dash but a hyphen, I'm guessing you don't want the user entering U+2013!

Comment: Good point. How about: "You may use period (.), underscore (_) and dash (-)." This resolves ambiguities and it still looks nicer (imho) than a list of symbols only. (Note, that I moved period to the front to avoid confusion with the period of the sentence).

Comment: @ChrisH For a non-English user A-z may include all the accented letters as they're sorted in their alphabet, so it doesn't help much. Something like "Latin letters without diacritics" would be more precise but probably also more confusing.

Comment: @maaartinus - even more to consider when it comes to international users! How about "A-z (no accents)"?

Comment: @ChrisH Someone could claim, that `A-z` includes also the six non-letters [in between](http://www.asciitable.com), but yes. It's short and clear (unless someone *wants* to misunderstand).

Comment: @maaartinus As a german I wouldn't even consider using any of the "non-english" letters like umlauts (äöü) or other special characters (ß) in a registration form, even on a german site. Same goes for email addresses and urls.

Comment: @RomanReiner The same for me as I know there are many keyboards lacking this funny stuff (e.g. mine - even though living in Germany, I'm using US keyboard). But I know there are users thinking differently.

Answer (score 4):

## tl;dr

You should show *all* valid or *all* invalid characters *before* the user starts to type into the field. This should be a hint. Keep it short, easy to understand and straightforward.

## Demonstration

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3eP50.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

## In depth explanation

### Example placeholders

Use fields with a placeholder that shows a valid example input. Example placeholders indicate the preferred format of the input. This could help for example in a telephone number field.

### Message on focus

Display a fixed label or a popup bubble when the user enters the field.
The user will see the hint *before* he starts to enter the input, so he can think of a different value if the one he wanted to entry is incorrect. This also solves the possible question that a user would ask before giving the input: "what should I write over here? Will my input correct?".

### Short and bold character list

Use short form of the valid characters like "a-z" not something like "alphanumerical only".
It's much easier to oversee and understand the accepted characters. You don't have to find out the meaning of the words like: "ok, alphanumerical characters are characters from a to z with numbers". Also clarifies obscurity like: "are uppercase letters allowed?".

I would also recommend [@NonNumeric's solution](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/57493/47161) with using bold on the allowed character list. This guides attention to the essence of the popup message.

### Feedback on blur

After the user filled the field and the focus is lost, you should validate the field.

- If the input is valid, show a check mark that indicates the valid input.
- If the input is invalid, leave the popup there and make it or the user field (or both) red, so it will indicate that something went wrong.

Thanks to this, if the user missed the guide before typing, he has a feedback after his input. The errors/check marks also simplify the overview of the filled form.

Answer (score 1):

One way to deal with this is to not say anything at all at first and then let the user know when a disallowed character is entered. If you use in-line validation and apply after each character input, the user (almost) won't even need to be notified of which character was forbidden.

It depends on what should go in the field. If the data that should go in the field follows a certain form (e.g. a postal code or something), there is a very limited set of characters that should end up there. Type-Os and very alternative ways of typing the data will be handled by the error message and the rest will just float by without even noticing.

It might be though, that the field is made for data that has less conventions around its format. In such case, the number of erroneous inputs may reach unacceptable levels and instructions pre-input is required.

Both in the inline error message and in the case where an info text is needed, I prefer writing "Letters and numbers" rather than "A-Z, a-Z, 0-9" because it's a lot easier to make sense of, and you can save the clutter for the special characters.

Ex: Please, use only letters, numbers and these special characters ( _   .   - )

Comment: I disagree. I hate it when I spend five minutes thinking of a new password for a site, only to be told that it’s unacceptable _after_ I’ve typed it.

Comment: Well, that's not exactly what I wrote now, was it...?

Comment: Well, you ***did*** say, “not say anything at all at first and then let the user know when a disallowed character is entered”.

Comment: ...when suitable, yes. I also said that fields for data with less convention around its format should use a different approach. Password is for sure one of them.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that your best bet is to use a table-like structure to clearly label and isolate each rule:

**CSS**

```
table{
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
td{
    padding:3px 6px 3px 6px;
    vertical-align:top;
    border:solid 1px #000;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<h3>Allowed characters</h3>
<table>
    <tr><td>Alphabet: lower-case and UPPER-case</td><td>A through Z<br>a through z</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Numbers</td><td>0 through 9</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Punctuation: period, underscore, hyphen</td><td>.<br>_<br>-</td></tr>
</table>
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/F74L8/**

So now if your list grows then you do not have to worry about future characters messing with any sort of formatting you may have chosen for previous characters.

Comment: This is very clear, but also extremely verbose. In most web forms I encountered, there would simply be no space to (dynamically) insert this kind of table when invalid characters are entered.

Comment: @user1884155 I agree to a very basic an narrow extent. If I were to implement this then my error message would simply read something like `Invalid characters detected<br><a href="open a modal window when clicked">Click to view list of allowed characters</a>`

Comment: 1. This describes how to implement a solution rather than how to present the information.
2. It is a bad implementation.  Table-based layout is not the correct way to present information that is not semantically tabular data.  It's a bad short-cut that can present all sorts of page layout issues.  You can achieve the intended layout using proper CSS and HTML markup

Comment: @BillDagg Yes I know `<table>`'s suck and I wouldn't use it in a real implementation but my answer does show how you can clearly present the information. The other solutions presented here are relying on a user's pre-disposition to identifying what bold means and when punctuation begins vs. allowed chars begin. I would imagine that an older person is going to have trouble with the web form in the first place so why create a cryptic design that may/may not be recognized? Also please read my first comment to get an idea of how to implement this without killing your page layout.

Comment: @BillDagg I think tables are perfectly fine for enumerations, and in the answer above there is an enumeration of size 3. I also think that in the context of this question (and the answer provided) a comment about the misuse of tables is out of place.

Comment: @user1884155: An enumeration is a list.  That's what the <li> tag is for.  I agree we shouldn't be talking about implementation but the answer is an implementation.  That was my first point.

Answer (score 0):

If you just allow all utf8 characters as input, you don't need to worry about how to explain it to the user. And it will save you a big headache when going global with your app/website.

If they have to enter an email, you can write "this email address is not valid according to internet standard RFC ". That is much easier and people will understand why they need to enter only those characters instead of thinking you are a meany.

Comment: I don't know that "most people" know what an RFC is?

Comment: According to *which* RFC?

Comment: @CharlesWesley `RFC: Request For Coitous` duhhhh =)

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid all the clutter, but to still provide all the descriptive information you want ahead of time, you could have a "link" near the input field that says something like "What characters are valid here.". When a person moves their mouse to (hovers their mouse over) the link, a "tooltip" is shown that describes what is valid, in whatever detail you want.

Answer (score 0):

If space isn't an issue, then use a vertical list with word and actual cues.

You can use

- Numbers (**0-9**),
- Letters (**A-Z** and **a-z**),
- Underscores (**_**),
- Hyphens (**-**), and
- Periods (**.**)

In any case, explain the valid characters *before* the user enters data, not after submission or upon typing.

Answer (score -1):

If you use the word "Alphanumeric" instead of writing `A-Z` and `0-9`, it will reduce the amount of clutter and be clearer to the user.

Comment: The trouble with using the word 'Alphanumeric' is that it doesn't include `. , _` etc.

Comment: Also for average user it takes a significant amount of cognitive effort  to go from  'Alphanumeric' to characters **a-z 0-9** and even then tiny doubt about **A-Z**.